# How to display chart generated in pbPlots library inside a GTK Image widget?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk4

I want to display chart inside my GTK4 application. I'm mixing C GTK with C++ library [pbPlots](https://github.com/InductiveComputerScience/pbPlots) and rest of the code. Unfortunately I get some garbage image.

[image: Some bad results]

Vast majority of chart generation example codes is not compatible with GTK4. Writing image to file and reading it to GTK Image widget is quite silly.

```
g++ $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o chart chart.cpp pbPlots/pbPlots.cpp pbPlots/supportLib.cpp $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 )
```

```
#include "pbPlots/pbPlots.hpp"
#include "pbPlots/supportLib.hpp"

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new ();

  bool success;
  StringReference *errorMessage = CreateStringReferenceLengthValue(0, L' ');
  RGBABitmapImageReference *imageReference = CreateRGBABitmapImageReference();

  std::vector<double> xs{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
  std::vector<double> ys{2, -1, -2, -1, 2};

  ScatterPlotSeries *series = GetDefaultScatterPlotSeriesSettings();
  series->xs = &xs;
  series->ys = &ys;
  series->linearInterpolation = true;
  series->lineType = toVector(L"dashed");
  series->lineThickness = 2;
  series->color = GetGray(0.3);

  ScatterPlotSettings *settings = GetDefaultScatterPlotSettings();
  settings->width = 600;
  settings->height = 400;
  settings->autoBoundaries = true;
  settings->autoPadding = true;
  settings->title = toVector(L"x^2 - 2");
  settings->xLabel = toVector(L"X axis");
  settings->yLabel = toVector(L"Y axis");
  settings->scatterPlotSeries->push_back(series);

  success = DrawScatterPlotFromSettings(imageReference, settings, errorMessage);
  std::vector<double> *pngdata;
  if(success){
    pngdata = ConvertToPNG(imageReference->image);
    //WriteToFile(pngdata, "example2.png");
    //DeleteImage(imageReference->image);
  }else{
    std::cerr << "Error: ";
    for(wchar_t c : *errorMessage->string){
      std::wcerr << c;
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
  }

  unsigned char* buffer = DoubleArrayToByteArray(pngdata);
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(buffer, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, settings->width, settings->height, settings->width * 3, NULL, NULL);

  // GdkPixbuf* pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("test.png", nullptr);
  GtkWidget* image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (image, settings->width, settings->height);
  gtk_widget_set_hexpand(image, TRUE);

  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), image, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), grid);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), settings->width+10, settings->height+10);
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  FreeAllocations();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: Maybe its the conversion of double array to byte array. What is there in your buffer is somewhat different that what GTK expects. I recommend debugging that area. Load image from a file and see how different is the data (format, value range, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is working correctly.

```
  std::vector<double> *pngdata;
  pngdata = ConvertToPNG(imageReference->image);
  unsigned char* buffer = DoubleArrayToByteArray(pngdata);
  GInputStream* stream = g_memory_input_stream_new_from_data(buffer, pngdata->size(), NULL);
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream (stream, NULL, NULL);
  GtkWidget* image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
```

[image]

```
#include "pbPlots/pbPlots.hpp"
#include "pbPlots/supportLib.hpp"
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication* app,
                      gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new ();


  bool success;
  StringReference *errorMessage = CreateStringReferenceLengthValue(0, L' ');
  RGBABitmapImageReference *imageReference = CreateRGBABitmapImageReference();

  std::vector<double> xs{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};
  std::vector<double> ys{2, -1, -2, -1, 2};

  ScatterPlotSeries *series = GetDefaultScatterPlotSeriesSettings();
  series->xs = &xs;
  series->ys = &ys;
  series->linearInterpolation = true;
  series->lineType = toVector(L"dashed");
  series->lineThickness = 2;
  series->color = GetGray(0.3);

  ScatterPlotSettings *settings = GetDefaultScatterPlotSettings();
  settings->width = 600;
  settings->height = 400;
  settings->autoBoundaries = true;
  settings->autoPadding = true;
  settings->title = toVector(L"x^2 - 2");
  settings->xLabel = toVector(L"X axis");
  settings->yLabel = toVector(L"Y axis");
  settings->scatterPlotSeries->push_back(series);

  success = DrawScatterPlotFromSettings(imageReference, settings, errorMessage);
  std::vector<double> *pngdata;
  if(success){
    pngdata = ConvertToPNG(imageReference->image);
    //WriteToFile(pngdata, "example2.png");
    //DeleteImage(imageReference->image);
  }else{
    std::cerr << "Error: ";
    for(wchar_t c : *errorMessage->string){
      std::wcerr << c;
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
  }

  unsigned char* buffer = DoubleArrayToByteArray(pngdata);
  GInputStream* stream = g_memory_input_stream_new_from_data(buffer, pngdata->size(), NULL);
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream (stream, NULL, NULL);
  GtkWidget* image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (image, settings->width, settings->height);
  gtk_widget_set_hexpand(image, TRUE);

  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), image, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), grid);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), settings->width+10, settings->height+10);
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  FreeAllocations();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

But:

1. Potentially is not optimal.
2. There is still need to take care of memory management. I hope
   g_autoptr() is adequate for that use case (unsigned char* buffer, GInputStream* stream, GdkPixbuf *pixbuf).
   I need to plot live chart from serial port, so picture will be updated during work.

[Serial monitor in GTK C++](https://github.com/rziomber/Serial-monitor-GTK-C/)